# C warning error: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args], with no format?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, printf, function-call

I am getting this problem in C programming. I'm new to C so I would like some help.

Anyine know why this is happening?

I'm trying to get the dir path using getcwd and I'm not even formatting so I don't get why I'm getting this warning? My code is below:

```
replace.c: In function ‘main’:
replace.c:49:8: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

```
printf("Search begins in current folder: ", 
       getcwd(currDir,
       sizeof(currDir)), "\n");
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you want `printf` to do with the two arguments, `getcwd(currDir, sizeof(currDir))` and `"\n"`, that you supplied after the format string?

Comment: You are assuming that strings are concatenated by `printf`. They are not. Read how to properly use `printf`, because nobody taught you this.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not Visual Studio.  And neither is relevant to your question.  Tags removed.  And when you post, [check the formatting](https://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/) - don't rely on others fixing it for you.

Comment: i got it figured it out, the problem was formatting it using %s\n. Thanks for the help, I need to learn more about C, my prof isnt the best lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string in the call of printf does not contain conversion specifiers. So the second and the third arguments apart from the format string  are redundant.

It seems you forgot to include the conversion specification `%s` in the format string.

For example

```
printf( "Search begins in current folder: %s\n", 
        getcwd( currDir, sizeof( currDir ) );
```

Pay attention to that the call of getcwd can return a null pointer. So you need to check the return value before using the call of printf.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the `getcwd()` function inside of the `printf()` function. That is why it is issuing a too many arguments error. If you want to get the current working directory using a `getcwd()`, then you can try using this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char cwd[256];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL){
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }
    else{
        printf("current working directory is: %s\n", cwd);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```